# Systemd service not executing my Python script

Tags: python, linux, daemon, systemd

I have my python script to schedule the creation of a text file in every 1 minutes of interval. I want to run this file in the background and it should be alive even after restarting the system.

My Python file:

```
import schedule
import time

#datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")


def job():
    print("Scheduling is Working...")
    createfile()

def createfile():
    company = "Example file"
    with open('company.txt', 'w+') as f:
            f.write(str(company))
            print("File Created on:",time.ctime(time.time()))
            f.close()
    return True
# schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
# schedule.every().hour.do(job)

#schedule.every().day.at("11.40").do(job)
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

- I'm using `systemd` to make service
- os is ubuntu 16 and pytho3

MY Systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run scheduler back
After=multi-user.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/dev/schedulerun.py > /var/log/sanu_daemon.log 2>&1
StandardInput=tty-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I checked about status, its working fine but not creating the text file
I couldn't figure out what is the error.

Comment: Have you checked permissions? What are the permissions on the script, who is the owner of it, permission on the folder where the file is created, etc..

Comment: It's trying to create file in working folder. What's the working folder of your service?

Comment: i gave chmod 644 on my folder /var/www/html/dev/ @Vinny  . And owner user and www-data

Comment: My working folder /var/www/html/dev @AmaroVita .

Comment: How have you determined that the file is not present? What does `ls -l /root/` output? Also note that the lines `f.close()` and `return True` don't do anything in your code, they can be safely removed. In addition, if you just want to execute one task regularly, why are you using a systemd service instead of cron?

Comment: total = 0 is the result of that command @phihag

Comment: Your Answer @phihag helped to run my program as desired, it created file also. But file is created by root . how can i run by user

Comment: @frankhk I'll write an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure working directory and user in the Service section:

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/dev/
User=frank
# or www-data, or whatever user you want ...

# Other settings, such as ...
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/dev/schedulerun.py > /var/log/sanu_daemon.log 2>&1
StandardInput=tty-force
```

For more information, refer to the [systemd.exec manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html).