# Linux / Raspberry Pi OS - Setting environment variable that will work with a systemd service

Tags: python-3.x, linux, environment-variables, systemd, systemctl

I asked [this question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73317732/linux-raspberry-pi-os-systemd-not-working-with-python3-script-using-os-modul) which in essence is regarding running a python3 script (that uses an environment variable set in **etc/enviroment**) that is run by a systemd service which I've named `mqtt.service`.

I got some useful information from an answer to that question indicating that by default environment variables in `/etc/environment` aren't accessible in **systemd**, and that answer linked [to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473001/env-vars-in-etc-environment-not-globally-visible) that details the steps you can take to allow the systemd service to see an enviroment variable of your choosing.

So far I've tried the following:

Within my service I’ve tried to add `EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment` which contains my environment variable: `export DEVICE_ID="TEST1"`. I’ve also tried using the `systemctl edit mqtt.service` to create `mqtt.service.d/override.conf` file that also has `EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment` set.

Next I tried instead to set the `Environment=$DEVICE_ID` in the `mqtt.service` directly as well as the `mqtt.service.d/override.conf` file.

I then tried all of the above but changing where the `$DEVICE_ID` environment variable was set. So far I’ve tried setting it in `etc/profile` with a value of `export DEVICE_ID="TEST1"`.

Finally I also tried creating a `device_id.sh` file within `/etc/profile.d/device_id.sh` which has a value of export `DEVICE_ID=TEST1`. Which gave me the following results when i tried to run the `mqtt.service`:

```
user@computer:/etc/profile.d $ sudo systemctl status mqtt.service
● mqtt.service - Arms the mqtt.py script that will alert if the device is moved
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mqtt.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mqtt.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-08-12 14:49:52 BST; 4s ago
    Process: 12941 ExecStart=python3 /scripts/mqtt.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 12941 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 551ms

user@computer:/etc/profile.d $ sudo systemctl status mqtt.service
● mqtt.service - Arms the mqtt.py script that will alert if the device is moved
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mqtt.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mqtt.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-08-12 14:49:52 BST; 4s ago
    Process: 12941 ExecStart=python3 /scripts/mqtt.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 12941 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 551ms
user@computer:/etc/profile.d $
```

Everything I tried above gave me simular error messages when trying to run the `mqtt.service`.

I'm really struggling with this, I don't know If I'm, missing something or is it the case that what I'm trying to achieve isn't possible?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [second answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522855/119298) to the link you gave, and `man environment.d`, the file `/etc/environment` is used to set variables in the **user** services environment, i.e. services started with `systemctl --user start ...`.  You are using **system** services, so if you want to include this file you needed to set

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
```

which you probably have by now. Make sure it is in the right section. You also need to run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` after editing a unit file.

However, the man page also explains that the format for lines in the environment file is extremely limited. In particular, the shell command `export` is not allowed. Although it is not mentioned, double-quotes are allowed, but not needed.
So you should try an entry like

```
DEVICE_ID=TEST1
```

You should do a `systemctl --user daemon-reload` after editing this file for it to be parsed and checked for errors, but you need to look for the error messages in one of the various system log files.  You can see any changes with
`systemctl --user show-environment`.

Comment: That helped, it turns out using export in the /etc/environment file was the culprit.